# I'm trying to output a filtered list on my Django template

Tags: django

For example, I have in models.py:

```
class Development(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    client = models.ForeignKey(InsName, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    platform = models.ManyToManyField(Platform)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and in views.py (with the corresponding url added to urls.py):

```
class DevelopmentFilterView(generic.ListView):
    model = Development
```

How do I tell my template to only output a list of the database entries for a certain client?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to define a `get_queryset` function in your View Class which returns a QuerySet of the Development model. Something like this should work:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Development.objects.filter(client__id=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the method get_queryset from ListView class, like this:

```
class DevelopmentFilterView(generic.ListView):
    model = Development
    queryset = Development.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self):
       qs = super().get_queryset()
       qs = qs.filter(client=client)
       return qs
```